# Is there a way to make custom browser default in iOS instead of Safari?

Tags: ios, safari, appstore-approval

Is there a way to programmatically make your app's custom browser the default one instead of Safari in iOS? I remember having seen one project that seemed to do something similar but unable to recollect which one it was? If it was possible, will Apple approve such apps or reject them?

Thanks,

Paddy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  and/or the store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for ask question

Please do refer this [link.](https://github.com/dfmuir/KINWebBrowser)

Might be it will help you.

You can use as follow.

1) Install library manually or using pods.
  2) Do use as follow.

```
UINavigationController *webBrowserNavigationController = [KINWebBrowserViewController navigationControllerWithWebBrowser];
[self presentViewController:webBrowserNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

KINWebBrowserViewController *webBrowser = [webBrowserNavigationController rootWebBrowser];
[webBrowser loadURLString:@"http://www.example.com"];
```

**Advantage of this library:**

Features

```
iOS 7 & 8 support for iPhone and iPad devices
Safari-like interface
Animated progress bar
Customizable UI including tint color
Portrait and landscape orientation support
Use with existing UINavigationController or present modally
Delegate protocol for status callbacks
Action button to allow users to copy URL, share, or open in Safari & Google Chrome
```

**UPDATE:**

Sorry for the huge misunderstanding between us.

I am sorry to say that is not Possible  to make custom browser default in iOS instead of Safari?

Comment: Hi @Hitesh,  I could not understand how this library helps in my case where I want Chrome nor Safari but instead my own browser to be default. Can you please help me understand?

Comment: In your app you can open URL directly withing your app instead of Open in safari. Do User feel like He/She interact with browser

Comment: I am afraid that isn't my requirement. My app already is a browser and I want any URL clicked anywhere in the iPhone (let's say a message or Note) to open my browser instead of Safari?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, But May be not possible.